# Can’t seem to find the C wire on the furnace in my new home

Tags: furnace

My wife and I just purchased a Mobile home and there is no C wire on the furnace to hook up the common wire. We came from a rented home where we already had a Nest and wanted to hook it up in our new home. Can someone help me figure out what wire is the common wire that I need to hook up the blue wire running to my thermostat?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A "C" wire would have to connect into the circuit as per the the wiring nodes highlighted in the blue color as shown below. A likely place to connect in would be the BLK wire that comes out to the optional COND. UNIT CONTACTOR and to the BLEND AIR CONTROL BOX.

[image]